# Convert EditText to TextView after inputting a name

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I want to input a name through `EditText` and then after inputting it should set itself as permanent so that there can't be anymore editing on the `EditText`. Basically, convert it to `TextView` and display the inputted name.

Answer (score 0):

Simple make the editext non editable like this

```
yourEditText.setFocusable(false);
yourEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
yourEditText.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Able to Edit

editText.setEnabled(true);

> Unable to edit

editText.setEnabled(false);